# Excel - Power Query 2016

Tags: excel, powerquery

I got data from two tables.

Customers (containing customer ID and the total value of orders/funding

Orders (Containing customer ID and each order)

[image]

I created a Power Query, then chose the option to "Merge Queries as New". Selected the matching Columns (Customer ID) and chose the option:Left Outer (All from the first and, matching from second => All from the customer table, matching from the order table). Then I expanded the last column of the Query to include what I wanted from the Order table resulting in the table below on the left. The one on the right is what I'm after. The problem is that funding amounts are already totals per customer. I don't need the value of each order broken down. I still need the orders displayed but I don't need their values (just the total per customer). Is it possible to do it like the one below on the right? Otherwise, the grand total is way off.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is join with only the first instance of each value in your `Customer` column. There doesn't appear to be any feature or GUI element that allows you to do that (I had a look at the [reference documentation for Power Query M](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-function-reference), maybe I missed something).

To replicate your data, I'm starting off with some tables (left table is named`Customers`, right table is named`Orders`):

[image: My tables]

I then use the `M` code below (the first few lines are just to get my tables from the sheet):

```
let
    customers = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Customers"]}[Content],
    orders = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Orders"]}[Content],
    merged = Table.NestedJoin(orders, {"CUSTOMER"}, customers, {"CUSTOMER"}, "merged", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    indexColumn = Table.AddIndexColumn(merged, "Temporary", 0, 1),
    indexes =
        let
            uniqueCustomers = Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(indexColumn, {"CUSTOMER"})), // Want to keep as table
            listOfRecords = Table.ToRecords(uniqueCustomers),
            firstOccurenceIndexes = List.Accumulate(listOfRecords, {}, (listState, currentItem) =>
                List.Combine({listState, {Table.PositionOf(indexColumn, currentItem, Occurrence.First, "CUSTOMER")}})
            )
        in
            firstOccurenceIndexes,
    expandSelectively =
        let
            toBoolean = Table.TransformColumns(indexColumn, {{"Temporary", each List.Contains(indexes, _), type logical}}),
            tableOrNull = Table.AddColumn(toBoolean, "toExpand", each if [Temporary] then [merged] else null),
            dropRedundantColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(tableOrNull, {"merged", "Temporary"}),
            expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(dropRedundantColumns, "toExpand", {"FUNDING"})
        in
            expand
in
    expandSelectively
```

If your table names and column names match mine (including case sensitivity), then you might just be able to copy-paste all of the `M` code above into the Advanced Editor and have it work for you. Otherwise, you may need to tweak as necessary.

This is what I get when I load the query to the worksheet.

[image: Query loaded]

There might be better (more efficient) ways of doing this, but this is what I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the order ID column, then I would suggest doing a Group By on the `OrderTable` before merging in the funding so that you'd end up with a table like this instead:

```
Region  Customer  OrderCount  Funding
South   A         3           2394
South   B         2           4323
South   C         1           1234
South   D         2           3423
```

This way you don't have mixed levels of granularity that cause problems like you are seeing with the totals.

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear in my question. I do need the order ID but I don't need the value of a particular order. In fact, I don't even have the value of a particular order in the Order table. Let me add some clarification in the question